# Saving colours plotting k-means cluster to see evolution through time

Tags: r, plot, k-means, pca

I'm doing a PCA on a crunchbase dataset, to analyse investments behaviour per year. I use R for this. I created plots for the years from 2000 to 2012. What I need to do though is to create a video in the end that shows how the investors (represented as dots) move over time. I'm using a k-means clustering and use the cluster for colouring.

**Here is my problem:** 
Every time I calculate the pca and k-means clustering for a new year, R plots the clusters in different colour.

**This is what I want to achieve:** 
Save the colour for each dot (represents an investment firm) for the initial year 2000, so if I calculate the PCA for the upcoming years, I plot that dot in the same colour from year 2000.

**Tricky Part:**
Over the years some investment firms are added, I don't want to colour those added throughout the years.

**This is how the initial plot from 2000 looks like:**
[image]

**This is what the plot from 2001 looks like:**

*This just coloured all the clusters in a different cluster. But does not take into the account the colour of the dots from the year 2000, so I can't compare it.*
[image]

**Here is an example of the code I use:**

```
inv.mat <- cast(invtop[,1:4], investor_name~company_market, sum)
inv.names <- inv.mat$investor_name
inv.mat <- inv.mat[,3:29] 
inv.log <- log(inv.mat)
inv.log[inv.log == -Inf] <- 0
fit <- kmeans(inv.log, 4, nstart= 30)
pca <- prcomp(inv.log)
pca <- as.matrix(pca$x)
plot(pca[,2], pca[,1], pch = 16, cex = 1 ,col = fit$cluster,   xlab="Principal Component 1", ylab="Principal Component 2", main="VC firms")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your problem:

- Do you want to keep the colours you had in the first plot? (Yes)
- Is your data input the same through the years? (No)

If you want to keep the colors from the first yerar, you just need to write `col=fit1$cluster` were `fit1` is your cluster analysis for the first TimePoint.

So, you need to build initially a vector (called `clus.col` for example) with all the available firms among the years.

The issue is that you need to define the color for each one and if you define it only for the first year you will probably miss some of them (unless in the first year there are presented all of them).
Once you have defined `clus.col` for each plot you should take a subset with only the individuals appearing on it.

Comment: Yes, the dots in the first plot represent an investment firm, and I want to assign that color to that specific firm. So that that investment firm has the same color in the other plots. 
My Data input is the following: "investor_name", "company_name", "company_market", "raised_amount_usd", "investor_market", "funded_year".   Basically the input changes throughout the year, since not every year every investment firm funded some company. So throughout the years firms are added or reduced.

Comment: I will edite my answer when knowing more details. Are in your first TimePoint all the available firms?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. So you say I have to build an initial vector with just all the available firm names. 
How would I then only color a subset of them in my initial plot. And how would I continue in the upcoming years?

Comment: If you have the vector `clus.col` with the color for all the firms, you only need to call `plot( . . ., col = clus.col[cl1.names])` being `cl1.names` a logicar vector indicating if the firm is taking part of the cluster analysis

Comment: It's not working as I expected it. So I have a named vector with all the available firms and a color value. I changed the color values of that named vector according to the year 2000 PCA cluster colors, such that all the other firms not available in 2000 PCA Clusters have a different value. Now when I want to assign the color: 'col = color[clusterColorInvestorNames]' it is still changing colors.

Comment: Are the names of `col = color[clusterColorInvestorNames]` and the individuals appearing in the cluster analysis in the same order?